# 楽天市場で検索したときにサイドバーにある商品価格の分布はどのようなアルゴリズムで表示されてますか

Tags: sql, アルゴリズム

楽天市場で検索したときにサイドバーにある商品価格の分布はどのようなアルゴリズムで表示されてますか

ぱっと思いつくのはSQLのGROUP BYを使うことですが、
数十万件ヒットする結果でも、非常に高速に表示されていて、
なにか集計用の高速に実行できるようなアルゴリズムがあるのではないかと思っています。

Answer (score 0):

SQL ではなく、全文検索エンジンの機能を使って実装しているいるのではないかと思います。
具体的には、Apache Solr の [ファセット](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/faceting.html) 、Elasticsearch の[アグリゲーション](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.4/search-aggregations.html)など。

こちらのサイトの「ファセット向けにクエリを投げ、その結果でファセットを作る機能を紹介」の部分で例があります。
[Apache Solr 5.xでファセットを試す - CLOVER](https://kazuhira-r.hatenablog.com/entry/20151003/1443892724)